# Symfony 2: Error with GregWare:ImageBundle and MAMP

Tags: php, symfony

I try to use GregWare:ImageBundle with MAMP.
When I try a

```
Image::open($this->file);
```

Symfony gives me a

```
Warning: imagejpeg(): Invalid 2nd parameter, it must a filename or a stream in /XXX/vendor /gregwar/image-bundle/Gregwar/ImageBundle/Image.php line 979
```

GD and EXIF are correctly installed.

In my debian server, I can use this bundle without any problems.

If I print `$this->file`, I can't find the corresponding file in my finder. I tried to `chmod` the folder without success.

EDIT:

In my controller, when i submit the form, i do that. File is "file" from file type.
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bind($request);

```
        if ($form->isValid()) {
                            $annonce->uploadMainFile();
            $annonce->setEnable(true);
            $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
            $em->persist($annonce);
            $em->flush();
            //TODO redirect
            return $this->redirect(
                    $this->generateUrl('xxx_core_moncompte'));
```

Here is my upload function in my main entity containing the file

```
public function uploadMainFile(){

        $hCible = 205;
        $lCible = 277;
        $ratioCible = $lCible/$hCible;

        if($this->file!=null){
            $size = getimagesize($this->file);
            $haut=$size[1];
            $larg=$size[0];
            $ratio = $larg/$haut;

            if($ratio>$ratioCible){

                //Resize by height
                Image::open($this->file)
                    ->resize(null, $hCible)
                    ->save($this->file);
     (...)
```

Comment: If you print `$this->file`, what does it show?

Comment: It display me Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpgyJxnA. I can't find this file with finder

Comment: What is `$this->file` supposed to contain? Do you have a link to the Bundle source/documentation?

Comment: It contains a temporary file in an image that I just upload

Comment: Can you show this part of the code?

Comment: Sure, i just do it in original post

Comment: I don't see a problem in your code...could this help: http://www.phpmysql.net/2011/01/01/php-file-uploading-of-large-files-in-mamp-pro/